# Nav Bar at Top using CSS

Tags: css, html

I want to get my nav bar to stick at the top when scrolling on the web page.

I have tried searching on here for a solution but am struggling as it is causing more errors.

When using `position:fixed`, I find that it causes issues with the original postion which I want to be below my banner logo.

My code for HTML and CSS is below.

Thank you

```css
/* ******************* */
/* Navigiation         */
/* ******************* */

#sitenav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: inherit;
    
}

#sitenav ul {
    background: black;
    padding: 15px;
}
#sitenav ul li {
    
    padding: 15px;
    background: black;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    display: inline;
}

#sitenav ul li:hover {
    background: rgb(43, 78, 89);
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<header class="clearfix">
   <div id="banner" class="middlecontent">
       <a href="index.html"><img  src="images/logobanner.png"></a>
   </div>
   <nav>
        <div  id="sitenav">
            <ul >
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Curriculum</a></li>
                <li><a href="about_us.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Student</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: You are looking for `sticky` (look at @cvgore answer)

Comment: Please check my answer I think this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to support older browsers, you can use `position: sticky`
https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning

Comment: It is mostly supported (for simple uses) https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

Comment: @MarioNikolaus `sticky` is actually [fairly well supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky) in most major browsers, with the caveat that certain elements (mostly sub-parts of tables) aren't currently supported. As long as you don't care about IE, it's viable to use. (You will also need to provide a prefixed version to Safari). And you can always polyfill for browsers that don't support it if you need to.

Comment: @UselessCode still think it is highly unsupported as opposed to fixed :) which can with almost no configuration be very powerful. Using polyfills just bulks up your code, who would nowadays want to add polyfill for that?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus `position:sticky` is still considered experimental, but standards wouldn't evolve if they weren't challenged. That being said, you could do a mix and apply a widely supported solution with `position:fixed` as a fallback, and then apply `position:sticky` for the browsers actually supporting it using `@supports(position:sticky){ header{ position:sticky } }` :o)

Answer (score 2):

Please try this I have added some code.

JQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= ($("header").height())) {
        $("#sitenav").addClass("fix-header");
    } else {
        $("#sitenav").removeClass("fix-header");
    }
});
```

Css:

```
body{
  margin:0;
}
section{
  background:#ccc;
  height:800px;
}
#sitenav.fix-header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin:0;
}
#sitenav.fix-header ul{
  margin:0; 
}
```

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= ($("header").height())) {
        $("#sitenav").addClass("fix-header");
    } else {
        $("#sitenav").removeClass("fix-header");
    }
});
```

```css
/* ******************* */
/* Navigiation         */
/* ******************* */

#sitenav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: inherit;    
}

#sitenav ul {
  background: black;
  padding: 15px;
}
#sitenav ul li {    
  padding: 15px;
  background: black;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  display: inline;
}

#sitenav ul li:hover {
  background: rgb(43, 78, 89);
  color:white;
  cursor:pointer;
}
body{
  margin:0;
}
section{
  background:#ccc;
  height:1000px;
}
#sitenav.fix-header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin:0;
}
#sitenav.fix-header ul{
  margin:0; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="clearfix">
 <div id="banner" class="middlecontent">
   <a href="index.html"><img  src="images/logobanner.png"></a>
 </div>
 <nav>
    <div id="sitenav">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Curriculum</a></li>
          <li><a href="about_us.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Student</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<!--this for demo for checking scroll-->
<section>

</section>
```

Comment: This question is about CSS... suggesting adding a 100k JS library when simply adding `position: sticky` to the style sheet would do it... isn't optimal... to say the least. If doing it with JS, it could be done with relatively little code without jQuery. If we knew they were already using jQuery this might be a okay suggestion... but without knowing that, I'm not sure this is a productive answer to the question.

Comment: @UselessCode Ok but please check question once because user want navbar sticky after scroll not want by default sticky that's why I have used jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this code.

```js
 $(window).ready(function() {
        var header = $('nav').innerHeight();
        var window_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (window_scroll >= header) $("nav").addClass("sticky");
        else $("header").removeClass("nav");
    })
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        var header = $('nav').innerHeight();
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= header) $("nav").addClass("sticky");
        else $("nav").removeClass("sticky");
    });
```

```css
nav{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
nav.sticky{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  z-index:99;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
#sitenav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: inherit;
    
}

#sitenav ul {
    background: black;
    padding: 15px;
}
#sitenav ul li {
    
    padding: 15px;
    background: black;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    display: inline;
}

#sitenav ul li:hover {
    background: rgb(43, 78, 89);
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<header class="clearfix">
   <div id="banner" class="middlecontent">
       <a href="index.html"><img  src="images/logobanner.png"></a>
   </div>
   <nav>
        <div id="sitenav">
            <ul >
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Curriculum</a></li>
                <li><a href="about_us.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Student</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>              
</body>
</html>
```